# jQuery filter with checkbox and li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a javascript filter with checkboxes as the filter criteria elements and hiding the respective `<li>` elements:

Here is rendered sample of my search filters:

```
<input type=[checkbox] class="filter" data-city="Memphis">
<input type=[checkbox] class="filter" data-city="Cordova">
<input type=[checkbox] class="filter" data-city="Bartlett">
```

And here are my results:

```
<li class="result" data-city="Memphis">Memphis</li>
<li class="result" data-city="Memphis">Memphis</li>
<li class="result" data-city="Cordova">Cordova</li>
<li class="result" data-city="Bartlett">Bartlett</li>
```

Here is my javascript, which isn't working quite like I want it to:

```
$('.filter').change(function(){
    var city = $(this).data("city");
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
        $('li.result').is('[data-city="'+city+'"]').show();
        $('li.result').not('[data-city="'+city+'"]').hide();
    }
    else{
        $('li.result').not('[data-city="'+city'"]').show();
    }
});
```

I end up with a toggle-like result. How do I make it to where for each input that is checked, show the li's that correspond with it, and hide the others? Also to unhide the ones when they become unchecked.

Comment: For one, you're missing a `+` in your `else` after `'+city'"])`.

Comment: @mikehomme - ah yes, that's a typo on my part from transposing it here. I did not copy and paste the code, it is correct on my actual file

Comment: The first thing you should do is to check the console for syntax errors and fixed them before posting a question. Then you should check the docs of [`jQuery.is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/), the `is` returns `true` and not a jQuery result set, so you can't call `show` on it. You already talke about filtering so why didn't you use [`jQuery.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On each checkbox click you can look up the corresponding item and checkbox to determine visibility.

Since you want everything visible when nothing is checked, and only filter down results if something is checked, additional logic is placed at the end of the handler for that specific case.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8xr6tz1w/1/)

```
$('.filter').change(function(){     
    //on each click, refresh visible / hidden for each item
    $('li.result').each(function(i, item){
      var city = $(this).data('city');
      var visible = $('input.filter[data-city="' + city + '"]:checked').length > 0;
      visible ? $(this).show() : $(this).hide();
    });

    //if no checkboxes are checked, show everything
    if($('input.filter:checked').length === 0) $('li.result').show();
});
```

Added some labels to the checkboxes to make testing easier.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="filter" data-city="Memphis"> memphis
<input type="checkbox" class="filter" data-city="Cordova"> cordova
<input type="checkbox" class="filter" data-city="Bartlett"> bartlett

<ul>
<li class="result" data-city="Memphis">Memphis</li>
<li class="result" data-city="Memphis">Memphis</li>
<li class="result" data-city="Cordova">Cordova</li>
<li class="result" data-city="Bartlett">Bartlett</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: They are all initially shown, and therefore all the checkboxes are unchecked by default. Then as I would go and start checking boxes to filter show only the ones I have checked and hide all the rest. So essentially the opposite of what you have here, haha.

Comment: I would like it to work like Amazon.com's [Refine feature](https://s3.amazonaws.com/techboomers/rich/rich_files/rich_files/000/003/092/large/ap-20a18-20amazon-20prime-20search-20filter-20image1.png)

Comment: Edited, not able to follow that link at the moment but this might be what you were looking for.

Comment: If I still have it backwards, a well placed `!` might do the trick for you `var visible = !$('input.filter[`...

Comment: Yes! Your edit is exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Starts with checkboxes unchecked and list visible. Check one and the others are hidden. Check another it shows. Uncheck one and it's hidden, but checked items remain shown.

```
jQuery('.filter').change(function(){
  var city = $(this).data("city");
  if(jQuery(this).is(":checked")){
    jQuery('li.result[data-city="'+city+'"]').show();
    jQuery('.filter').each(function (key, value) {
      if ( jQuery(value).is(':not(:checked)') ) {
        jQuery('li.result[data-city="'+jQuery(value).attr('data-city')+'"]:not(:checked)').hide();
      }
    });
  }
  else{
    jQuery('li.result[data-city="'+city+'"]').hide();
  }
});

<input type=checkbox class="filter" data-city="Memphis">Memphis
<input type=checkbox class="filter" data-city="Cordova">Cordova
<input type=checkbox class="filter" data-city="Bartlett">Bartlett
<ul>
  <li class="result" data-city="Memphis">Memphis</li>
  <li class="result" data-city="Cordova">Cordova</li>
  <li class="result" data-city="Bartlett">Bartlett</li>
</ul>
```

[JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/sapolehipa/edit?html,js,output)